# How to prevent Entity Framework from adding existing objects to database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of objects that I am passing as a parameter to my Azure API.
I have wrapped the list into an object called `CheckAvailabilityRequest`.

```
class CheckAvailabilityRequest {
    public List<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When I receive the request on my server I create an object `MyObject2` and assign that `List<MyObject>` to it.

```
class MyObject2 {
    List<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}

MyObject2.MyObjects = request.MyObjects;
```

When calling

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_aaa.MyObject'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'aaa.MyObject'. The duplicate key value is (594229de-8384-4b3c-8c8f-4d081918f145).

I know this is because of disconnected states of the objects.

The list of `MyObject` already exists in the database.

But there must be a way of simply assigning the existing `MyObjects` without having them added to the database, is there?

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to do here. Why even assign the objects if you dont want them in the DB on SaveChanges? If you are you having issues with add vs update on the list navigation property then you have to check the PK value and mark it as added or modified manually.

Comment: They are in the database. They have been retrieved by my mobile application earlier, where the user picked some of them. Now they are passed back to a second API, where a new MyObject2 is created, with a reference to that List (which does not currently work).

Comment: Still have no clue. Why are you even attaching them to the new MyObject2 if you dont want them saved? We need way more context on what is going on here.

Comment: What @br4d is saying here is that you're somehow marking all `MyObject`s as `Added`. You should mark the ones having a primary key value as `Detached` or `UnChanged` or `Modified`, according to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I fixed it now, I used a wrong approach. Now I just pass the IDs of the MyObjects and on the server use the context.Find() method to retrieve the list. Beginner's Mistake ;)